# Listener not receiving IPN messages

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I've built a listener to capture PayPal transactions using IPN into Salesforce.  However, it's only receiving a small percentage of our PayPal transactions.

I've determined that they're not always being sent by:

1. I manually send (url-hack) a never before seen IPN string on the listener page.  It processes immediately and perfectly.
2. I go to PayPal and instruct the site to resubmit the same IPN

Since it's a known transaction my system will send an error message.  I've verified this 
by repeating step 1.

The message that should be produced by step 2 never arrives.  The other IPNs that were also resubmitted during step 2 also never appeared in Salesforce.

Your insights are greatly appreciated as this is amazingly frustrating!

Steve

Addendum
Based on advice in a comment from @Andrew Angell below, here's more information...

All of the IPN histories look like the following.  Notice the Notification URL.  Could my problem be that it doesn't contain my listener page or even match my IPN Notifier setting (which I just double checked)?

Also all of the transactions have a response code of 200 and zero retries.

[image]

Comment: Check out this article on [testing PayPal IPN](https://www.angelleye.com/test-paypal-ipn/).  If you follow all of those steps you should be able to track down your issue.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to your site.  Is "200 OK" you mention the same as "200" (w/o the "OK")?

Comment: HTTP 200 always means OK.

Comment: Response 200 means the script is completing successfully, so if you're not seeing what you expect to see happen when the script runs then your logic must not be doing what you think it is.  That's where testing directly inside the browser like the tutorial mentions can help because you can set output to see exactly what's running and what's not.

Comment: I've found that the reason I'm having trouble is that I'm not being sent the IPNs - they're going to a different URL despite my setting in PayPal.

Thanks to all for your help...now I have to get PayPal to assist.